# cocos2d-x, share or reuse CCTexture2D

Tags: cocos2d-x

In my game, every single character have same textures. 
So if there are 100 characters in a scene, 
there should be 100 sprites with textures, 
and there could be a memory problem.

So I think if it's possible to share one single CCTexture2D,(I mean one memory allocation)
the memory usage will be drop dramatically.

is it possible with static or global declaration?

Any comments plz~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With m.ding's answer,
I resolved my question.

Here is the solution.

step 1) define texture as batch node.

```
batchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("mans.pvr.ccz");
this->addChild(batchNode);
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("mans.plist");
```

step 2) create sprite with batch node's texture and add it to a scene.

```
CCSprite *man = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("body_black.png");
batchNode->addChild(man, 1, 1000);
```

step 3) if you want to change texture, just use batch node's cached texture.

```
((CCSprite *)this->getChildByTag(1000))->setDisplayFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName("body_red.png""));
```

That's it~. hope this help!

**Update** : add to batch node, not 'this'.  :)

Comment: i think it should be batchNode->addChild(man) will increase the performance. LearnCocos2D is right, it won't affect the memory usage.

Comment: what's the difference? this vs batchNode

Comment: `this` is every sprite calls one draw() method, `batch` is for all the sprite there is only one draw() is been called.

Answer (score 4):

Same sprite, same texture. A game engine that wouldn't optimize this case couldn't really call itself a game engine.

If you have a sprite using "tex.png" then tex.png will be loaded into memory. If you add a gazillion more sprites also using tex.png then only the sprite object itself will use more memory (a few hundred bytes) but the texture is re-used once it has been loaded. Ie you'll have a gazillion plus one sprites, all drawing from the same texture.

Using sprite batch node to increase rendering speed of those sprites using the same texture still applies and comes highly recommended, but it won't affect memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

CCSpriteBatchNode will be your best friend.

First you create a BatchNode with the texture file that you wanna use.

Then just add the 100+ Sprite to your batch. They use only one copy texture.

Comment: Okay, then I can create sprite with batch node like this. CCSprite *aMan1 = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("head.png"); but how can I change character's texture using the batch node textures?